# My onSubmit form is not working, it might be a component stopping it, how can I get more diagnostic information?

Tags: forms, material-ui

I have got a form with many components inside (and I can't share the code). When I click on a submit button, the `onSubmit` function is not triggered.

Here is `onSubmit`

```
const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log('a')
}
```

Form is something like

```
<form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
{many components}
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Clicking the button display nothing in the console and seemingly does nothing.

I suspect a component is stopping the form submit — for instance, using a required on a `TextField` will stop the `onSubmit` till you fill it — but I can't find it.

Is there a way to find which component is not happy through some function I could call from the form, rather than going through every component and find the faulty one ?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the event handler to the button itself. This should allow you to submit the form when you "Click" on the button. If you press enter on your keyboard the form should submit as you have your code now.

```
<form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
{many components}
<button type="submit" onClick={onSubmit}>Submit</button>
</form>
```